# jqGrid error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'savetext' of undefined

Tags: jqgrid, runtime-error

I have jqGrid JS 4.7.1 (2014-12-16).  I want to handle my own saving.  This is how I'm calling edit row:

```
    var editparameters = {
        "keys" : true,
        "oneditfunc" : function(a){console.log('oneditfunc');},
        "successfunc" : function(a){console.log('successfunc');},
        "url" : 'clientArray',
        "extraparam" : {},
        "aftersavefunc" : function(a){console.log('aftersavefunc');},
        "errorfunc": function(a){console.log('errorfunc');},
        "afterrestorefunc" : function(a){console.log('afterrestorefunc');},
        "restoreAfterError" : true,
        "mtype" : "POST" // I also tried null for this
    };

    grid.editRow(id, editparameters);
```

When I'm done editing a cell, and I press enter in the text input, I get this error in jqgrid:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'savetext' of undefined  (jquery.jqGrid.js:9892)
```

My goal: handle my own saving to the model as well as posting to server without an error in jqgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you forgot to include `grid.locale-en.js` file before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

You are not the first person who have the problem. Exactly because of that I removed the requirement in [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#the-following-new-features-are-implemented-comparing-with-jqgrid-47) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki#overview-of-the-main-changes))